# Compare the first position, with the next in a list

Tags: python

¡hello everyone!

I have to compare a position in a list with the next position in the same list. ls[0] with ls[1], ls[1] with ls[2]

what I have to do is to compare the list with the matching characters, and if they match, add a dot, and then print only once the letter that repeats and the number of times it repeats:

ls = "DDDDTTTDAATTTAAAUYUUU"

the output must be:

D T D A T A U Y U

4 3 1 2 3 3 1 1 3

I have already made the code, which is as follows:

```
n = "DDDDTTTDAATTTAAAUYUUU"
con = 1
a = ""
d = ""
for i in range(len(n)-1):
    if n[i] == n[i+1]:
        con += 1
    else:
        d += " " + str(n[i])
        a += " " + str(con)
        con = 1

print(d)
print(a)
```

the output:

```
D T D A T A U Y
4 3 1 2 3 3 1 1
```

as you can see, in the output of my code the last character [U] is missing as well as the number [3].

What is missing in my code to make it work correctly, I thank you for your help

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. Can you [edit] the question to include what you've tried to far, and where you are stuck? Refer [help] on asking good questions for more details we would like to see in posts

Comment: sorry I don't manage stackoverflow yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
n = "DDDDTTTDAATTTAAAUYUUU"
con = 1
a = ""
d = ""
for i in range(len(n)-1):
    if n[i] == n[i+1]:
        con += 1
    else:
        d += " " + str(n[i])
        a += " " + str(con)
        con = 1

# you are just missing this 
# when the loop finishes you have to concatenate
# a and d also

d += " " + str(n[i])
a += " " + str(con)  

print(d)
print(a)
```

```
 D T D A T A U Y U
 4 3 1 2 3 3 1 1 3
```

Comment: Hahahahah thanks 

me thinking of a lot of solutions, and it was just putting that hahahha. 

I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [(e,len(list(g))) for (e,g) in itertools.groupby(s)]
>>> l
[('D', 4), ('T', 3), ('D', 1), ('A', 2), ('T', 3), ('A', 3), ('U', 1), ('Y', 1), ('U', 3)]
```

If you need two separate lists, you can use always list comprehension to split them.

```py
>>> [x for (x,y) in l]
['D', 'T', 'D', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'U', 'Y', 'U']
>>> [y for (x,y) in l]
[4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Less duplicated code than the other answer. It essentially iterates one time too many, and writes the pending accumulated results at that last iteration before exiting the loop.

```
n = "DDDDTTTDAATTTAAAUYUUU"
con = 1
a = ""
d = ""
for i in range(len(n)): # do one more iteration
    if i < len(n) - 1 and n[i] == n[i+1]: # as long as we have not gone past the end of the string, and the char is identical to the next one
        con += 1
    else:
        d += " " + str(n[i])
        a += " " + str(con)
        con = 1

print(d)
print(a)
```